# How do i populate a dropdown menu from an array and select an option that is added to a table

Tags: html, vue.js

I wanted to use the json data array in this link to populate a dropdown menu and and upon selection, the option is added to a table on the next page. I want to be able to add and delete rows within the table with a confirmation modal.

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos. - url
```

my code
    https://codepen.io/asmafayaz1992/pen/LYPxrOe
How do I do in VueJS?

Comment: Hi Asma, you should put your code _here_, in a stack snippet, instead of (or in addition to) a codepen.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am currently unable to put my code here.

Comment: Did you want to be able to submit multiple on the first page? Or just one?

Comment: yes I did want to be able to submit multiple on the first page.

Comment: I notice some errors in the browser console when running your codepen - several _'Property or method "x" is not defined…'_. Your `<select...>` uses `v-model="select"` but there is no member named "select" (that I could find) in your Vue model.

Comment: How do I fix this?